# Problems with If two cells are zero formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want a cell to calculate only when two other cells add up to zero. But it appears that there is something wrong with this formula:

`=IF(AND(I20=0,J20=0,0,IF(I20>0,J20>0,(I20-J20+K19))))`

I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Truth Table]

See the Truth Table for your formula (if I understand your question correctly). The one in yellow does the service for the first 4 conditions. If the 5th is also needed, use the formula in green. Replace the terms "Calc" and "Don't Calc" with your formulas to calc depending on the comparison result.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, with the elements missing what from what seems likely you wanted, you have, in essence, the following formula:

```
=IF( AND( 4 things being tested as TRUE or FALSE, one of which will always be FALSE so the result will always be FALSE ) )
```

So even if the formula would calculate, it would always return FALSE in its cell. However, it cannot calculate because, as an `IF` with just a test and literally nothing else, it is written improperly and Excel will not even take it without it being fixed.

For information, an `IF` must always have at least one comma after the test or it will not be accepted as adequately written. So `IF(1>0)` will not work, while `IF(1>0,)` will. As written, its result will look odd, but it will work.

But surely you do not want one long `AND` in there. Surely you want the first `AND` where it is and a second `AND` after the second `IF`. So something like this:

```
=IF( AND(I20=0,J20=0),  0,  IF( AND(I20>0,J20>0),  (I20-J20+K19)  ))
```

which would work... though the lack of a result for the second `IF` being FALSE could be a problem (there being nothing after the `(I20-J20+K19)` part). If that can never happen, then it's just fine. But if it can, you need something added. And... surely it can or you wouldn't need the `IF` at all, just the `(I20-J20+K19)` part.

However, the above formula will work:  it tests for both being =0, and gives a 0 if so. Then it tests for both being >0 and gives the `(I20-J20+K19)` calculation if so. Nothing else is provided for, but if other things can happen, you might like to do so. If no other situation can happen, then the following would work fine and be simpler:

```
=IF( AND(I20=0,J20=0),  0,  (I20-J20+K19)  )
```

Back to the original for a moment, I said it would always return FALSE. As it's written, the `AND` tests that I20=0 (true or false), J20=0 (true or false), 0 (not even a test... but when looking for TRUE/FALSE results, Excel regards a "0" as FALSE and any other value as TRUE... so that "0" give the `AND` a FALSE so it immediately resolves the result to FALSE and the `IF` looks for what to do and finds nothing.

That's why I said that, as written, even providing the comma/s at the end of the `IF` would still not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to show us more details, such as a simple sample.

Please check whether the formula is helpful.

`=IF(I20+J20=0, "", (I20-J20+K19) )`